# Xamarin.iOS - Automatic Provisioning fails

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to set up my Xamarin.iOS project on Visual Studio 22 for PC, when trying to set the Automatic Provisioning, I keep getting the following error:

> This request is forbidden for security reasons: Authentication Error.
> XCode 7.3 or later is required to continue developing with your Apple
> ID.

Isn't the whole point of Xamarin is cross-platform developments? What would-I use XCode then?

I should also mention that the apple ID used has a valid developer subscription, and I do not have a Mac for any work-around requiring one.

Comment: All iOS development ultimately needs the toolchain that is part of Xcode regardless of the language/development system you use.  You will need need macOS and Xcode to actually build an iOS app.  You can use cloud-based build services

Comment: I see, I took a look at VS app center, but I don't think they provide some sort of iOS emulator to run the app, only build the ipa file without running, am-I wrong?

Comment: Correct. You cannot actually run the app without a Mac and you should also run on a real device before release; the simulator isn't the same

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows) :

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.4 and older), you will need to be Paired to a Mac build host before proceeding.

You can try [free provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows) which allows you to deploy and test their apps on iOS devices without being part of the Apple Developer Program.